# Month Date Range Picker - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm looking for a library like bootstrap date-picker for Vue.js .
But I need one where I can make some configuration like this one I'm using in a bootstrap daterange-picker

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
         format: "mm/yyyy",
         language: "es",
         autoclose: true,
         startView: 1,
         minViewMode: 1
});
```

I have some example code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jcldh8

I'm having some trouble using Vue js with this library so I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I`m using element ui for Vue.js.

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker

```
<el-date-picker
      v-model="birthdate"
      type="date"
      placeholder="Pick a Date"
      format="mm/yyyy"
      value-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
</el-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many libraries for Vue js that you can use easily like Element Ui, Vuetify etc.
but you can use Element UI that is very easy to use and it has so many nice features like bootstrap.

you can install it by npm or use by cdn, see documentation [here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation)

and components [date picker](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker)

Calling Element Ui date picker:

```
    <el-date-picker
      v-model="value2"
      type="date"
      placeholder="Pick a day"
      :picker-options="pickerOptions1">
    </el-date-picker>
```

For Vuetify you can [go here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start), it also can install in npm node or use cdn.

Vuetify date picker:

```
<v-date-picker 
  v-model="picker" 
  :landscape="landscape" 
  :reactive="reactive">
</v-date-picker>
```